Proving: $\sum_{i=0}^{n-k} \binom{n-k}{i} (k-1+i)(n-1)^{n-k-1-i} = kn^{n-k-1}$
To prove: $\sum_{i=0}^{n-k} \binom{n-k}{i} (k-1+i)(n-1)^{n-k-1-i} =  kn^{n-k-1}$
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n-k} \binom{n-k}{i}  (k-1) (n-1)^{n-k-1-i} + \sum_{i=0}^{n-k} \binom{n-k}{i} i (n-1)^{n-k-1-i}$$
$$ = (k-1) \sum_{i=0}^{n-k} \binom{n-k}{i} 1^i (n-1)^{n-k-1-i} + \sum_{i=0}^{n-k} \binom{n-k}{i} i (n-1)^{n-k-1-i}$$
$$ = (k-1)(1 + (n-1))^{n-k-1} + \sum_{i=0}^{n-k} \binom{n-k}{i} i (n-1)^{n-k-1-i}$$
$$= (k-1)n^{n-k-1} + \sum_{i=0}^{n-k} \binom{n-k}{i} i (n-1)^{n-k-1-i}$$
$$= (k-1)n^{n-k-1} + \sum_{i=0}^{n-k} \frac{n-k}{i}\binom{n-k-1}{i-1} i (n-1)^{n-k-1-i} \quad \text{Absorption identity}$$
$$= (k-1)n^{n-k-1} + \sum_{i=1}^{n-k} \binom{n-k-1}{i-1}(n-k) (n-1)^{n-k-i} $$
but I have absolutely not idea how to continoue. The paper I am reading states that the absorption identity and splitting the sums should suffice for proving but I just can't manage it. If someone could point out where my error is or finish the prove for me, I would be very grateful.

This question is similar to: Explain the last line of this proof (it's an identity I can't figure out)?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Found using an Approach0 search. ...

(cont.) Note that although the question only asks about the last line of their proof, the answer there gives a full explanation, roughly similar to the answer here below. Finally, welcome to Math SE.

To split the sum, you can write $k - 1 + i = (n - 1) - (n - k - i)$ and use the absorption identity
$$
\binom{n - k}{i} (n - k - i) = \binom{n - k - 1}{i} (n - k)
$$
which gives :
$$ 
\binom{n - k}{i} (k - 1 + i) (n - 1)^{n - k - 1 - i} \\ = \binom{n - k}{i} (n - 1)^{n - k - i} - (n - k) \binom{n - k - 1}{i} (n - 1)^{n - k - 1 - i}
$$
Then you take the sum, and with the binomial expansion you get :
$$
\sum_{i = 0}^{n - k} \binom{n - k}{i} (k - 1 + i) (n - 1)^{n - k - 1 - i} = n^{n - k} - (n - k) n^{n - k - 1} = k n^{n - k - 1}
$$

How do I formally derive the use of absorption identity here? Because I don't really see how that works
